# I cant figure out how to get all of my information to output to the text file correctly

Tags: c++

I'm working on this project and I can't figure out how to get all of my info to out put to the text file it seems to only output the last bit of info that was input. Before putting in the new header before the averages output I could only manage to get it to place the average in the text file. Help me please!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class FamilyMember
{
    private:
        int age;
        string name;

    public:

        FamilyMember();
        ~FamilyMember(){}

    void setName(string memberName)
    {name = memberName;}
    void setAge(int memberName)
    {age = memberName;}
    int getAge()
    {return age;}
    string getName()
    {return name;}
    void printFamilyMemberInfo();
};

FamilyMember::FamilyMember()
{
    age = 0;
}

void FamilyMember::printFamilyMemberInfo()
{
    ofstream dataFile;

    dataFile.open("myFamily.txt", ios::out);

    dataFile << name << endl;

    dataFile << age << endl;

}

int main()
{

    vector<FamilyMember> list;
    string Name;
    int Age, x, n;

    fstream dataFile;

    FamilyMember *c;

    cout << "Input number of family members";

    cin >> x;

    for(n = 0; n < x; n++)
    {
        cout << "Enter name:";
        cout << endl;
        cin >> Name;
        cout << "Enter age:";
        cout << endl;
        cin >> Age;

        c = new FamilyMember;
        c->setName(Name);
        c->setAge(Age);
        list.push_back(*c);
    }


    vector<FamilyMember>::iterator v;

    for(v = list.begin(); v != list.end(); ++v){

        v->printFamilyMemberInfo();
    }

    double a, b;

    for(n = 0; n < x; n++)
    {
        a += list.at(n).getAge();
    }

    b = a / x;

    std::ofstream datafile("myFamily.text", std::ios_base::out |                 std::ios_base::app);

    dataFile << "Average age is: " << b << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm not a C++ developer but I can tell you confidently, that the problem is that your overwriting every line with each new line thats passed from the output buffer. Therefore it *looks* like its only outputting the last line, but its actually outputting all of them on top of one another. Google 'append to file C++'

Comment: Are the two file names supposed to be different?
One is `myFamily.txt` and the other is `myFamily.text` with the `e` in text.

Comment: Haha nope they're supposed to be the same. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

try openning ofstream in append mode instead of `ios::out`

```
void FamilyMember::printFamilyMemberInfo()
{
    ofstream dataFile;

    dataFile.open("myFamily.txt", ios::app); // OPEN IN APPEND MODE

    dataFile << name << endl;

    dataFile << age << endl;

}
```

Comment: Hmmm now it will print both the name and age, but doesn't print average. I'm sorry I'm not too familiar with text operations I'm very new to C++.

Comment: Okay never mind I got it figured out! Thanks a ton that was part of the problem, and thanks all for your replies, they all helped immensely!